# Automatic adding parameter to link from email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

In Marketing Cloud, we have created a set of emails and landing pages that will be copied and edited into different languages by a variety of business units.

We need to somehow track what email a recipient clicks a link to a landingpage in order to change content in that landingpage (header image and such depend on what email the link is in).

We cannot rely on that all email editors will remember to add a variable like for instance "&email=newsletter" to every link.

So how can we add a function in an email, that secretly adds this variable to every link, how ever the editor edits the visible content in an email?

Is there another way to "tag" an email? So if "tag" == "newsletter" then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at the [**Web-Analytics Connector (WAC)**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) and the [**Additional Email Attributes**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/#HOWTOPLANforWEBANALYTICINTEGRATION) that can be enabled in the Email Properties.

SFMC Support can enable the WAC that will add parameters and values to every outbound link.  These parameter values can be set to populate from the Additional Email Attributes fields that you define in each email.